# Live_ISS_Stream stopped?

Tags: iss, nasa, crewed-spaceflight, communication

so I've come across [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=okk10DjnQk8), 11 hours of ISS transmissions during 2021 ASAT incident by Russia. The description says the footage was archived from [this IBM stream site](https://video.ibm.com/channel/live-iss-stream), so I've looked to see if it was live from time to time, but it seems it is always off-air. Has the stream been stopped since 2021? Is there any other way I can listen to live ISS comms? Also, are there any archives of past transmissions anywhere? Thank you

edit1: it turned out NASA's [ISS stream](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1rcSyN74BY0) contains Space to Ground audio. Though how to archive this is another question I guess.

I also found [Space Station Audio Collection](https://archive.org/details/spacestationaudiocollection?sort=title) that NASA has uploaded on Internet Archive, but the recordings are limited to stuff like inflight events and such.

Comment: They ended the 24/7 broadcast of ISS comms a few years ago. I can't seem to find the news articles from when they did that, but when/if I do, i'll post it as an answer